# Explanation of the chrome driver instantiation in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Driver:

    def instantiate_chrome_driver(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

In the above code, what is 'Chrome' as used in the second line of the function 'instantiate_chrome_driver' ? when I go to declaration in intellij, it takes me to the init method of the webdriver.py file in chrome module.However, I cannot see a method 'Chrome'.

I worked in java and webdriver. Now trying to get my head around the webdriver python implementation. I am new to python. Please be gentle :)

Comment: It's just an alias for the `chrome` version of the `WebDriver` class - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py#L20; IntelliJ is taking you to the correct place.

Comment: Thanks. That's something new I learned in Python today.

Comment: I will accept if you can post it as answer.